# Shape Drawable with only two sides

Tags: android

I am trying to implement in XML a ShapeDrawable like this, but so far without success.

[image]

How do I make the Stroke visible only for two sides?

Is that even possible?

Otherwise what cloud I use (I seed it as background of a TextView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible with a single `ShapeDrawable`. A nine-patch PNG, or a `LayerListDrawable` of two `ShapeDrawables` (one per line) should work though.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution which is using a `LayerListDrawable`:

**background_white_lateral_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <inset
            android:insetLeft="1dp"
            android:insetRight="1dp" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Note:** This firstly draws a white rectangle and then a black rectangle with a left and right inset of `1dp` on top of it, giving the effect of lateral borders. It's just something to keep in mind, in case you worry about performance (which is in my opinion negligible for minor styling like this).

Comment: Great answer only -the 1st item should have color black and 2nd as white to get what the question ask.